# Do murderers have "the eyes of a killer"?

Tags: psychology, criminology

Has there been any research in criminology, psychology, or some other related field? Something that shows a correlation between the everyday facial expression someone wears on their face, and whether they have murdered someone? In the absence of research, is there at least an expert opinion?

Comment: [Related!](http://www.thebestpageintheuniverse.net/c.cgi?u=spot_the_pedo)

Comment: @David: In S8E8 *Old People* of *Penn & Teller's Bullshit!* they interviewed the author of the thebestpageintheuniverse.net website. They declared him an a--hole. I wouldn't take the link for serious.

Comment: @Martin: haha, no, it's a comedy site, alright. There's nothing serious about it, but it's got a lot of gems. He has also made [a wonderful parody of the conspiracy video 'loose change'](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saHs6J0OXVI)

Comment: http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/files/2012/05/HP1-300x195.jpg - *"Any fool could look at 11-year-old Voldemort and know he was going to grow up to be a mass murderer"* -  Jack B Nimble

Comment: Murderers necessarily have the eyes of a killer, unless their eyes have been removed or something.

Answer (score 13):

The field of trying to work out a person's personality from their face is called [Physiognomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physiognomy).

Wikipedia claims:

> It is now being revived again as some new research indicates that people's faces can indicate such traits as trustworthiness, social dominance and aggression. The latter trait seems to be determined by the level of the hormone testosterone during puberty, which affects the ratio between the height and width of the face - aggressive individuals are found to have wider faces.

There are references there about detecting people's political preferences too.

I would expect (without evidence) that detecting criminality would be swamped more by factors of clothes, cosmetics (including hairstyles and tattoos) and racial profiling than actual facial characteristics.